# what format must have my custom CONTENT_FILTER_URI?

Tags: android, listview, android-contentprovider, android-loadermanager

I have a listview that I’m populating from a sqlite database via LoaderManager and also I want to be able to filter this list.

I’m following the example from the android documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#example

But I hit a road block at this point:

if (mCurFilter != null) 
{

baseUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(mCurFilter));

}

I don’t know what CONTENT_FILTER_URI should look like.

All the examples that I could find are talking about filtering phone contacts using Phone. CONTENT_FILTER_URI, but in my case I need a custom CONTENT_FILTER_URI similar to the

CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITIES + "/" + DataBase.TABLE);

from my extended ContentProvider class that I have implemented.

So what format must it have?

I don’t understand much from the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#CONTENT_FILTER_URI

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was over complicating things. I reused CONTENT_URI.